# SQLite and LINQ: find all objects that have a sub list with all ids present in a supplied list of IDs

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-5.0

I have the following class:

```
public class Article
{
    long Id;
    List<Category> Categories;
}
```

I am using EF Core 5 and What I need is a LINQ query against SQLite that returns all the articles that have all the categories that I specify.

I tried the following code:

```
List<long> cIds = c.Select (x => x.Id).ToList ();
query.Where (art => cIds.All (cId =>  art.Categories.Select (c => c.Id).Contains (cId)));
```

but the compiler says

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Article>()
.Where(a => __cIds_0
.All(cId => DbSet<Dictionary<string, object>>("ArticleCategory")
.Where(a0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(a, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(a, "Id"),
objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(a0, "ArticlesId")))
.Join(
inner: DbSet<Category>(),
outerKeySelector: a0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(a0, "CategoriesId"),
innerKeySelector: c => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(c, "Id"),
resultSelector: (a0, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<Dictionary<string, object>, Category>(
Outer = a0,
Inner = c
))
.Select(ti => ti.Inner.Id)
.Any(p => p == cId)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

How can I obtain it?

A possible workaround I found is the following:

```
List<long> cIds = c.Select (x => x.Id).ToList ();
query = query.Where (art => art.Categories.Select (c => c.Id).Any (x => cIds.Contains (x)));
query = query.Include (x => x.Categories);

result = await query.ToListAsync ();
result = result.Where (art => cIds.All (cId => art.Categories.Select (c => c.Id).Contains (cId))).ToList ();
```

But I was wondering if I could obtain the same result with a single LINQ query.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

I'll just add the function where this code will be used and make make an example to make things clearer:

This is the function where the code will be used:

```
public                  async   Task<List<Article>>     SearchAsync                     (string search, Section s, Website w, 
                                                                                    List<Category> c)
{
    List<Article> result = new List<Article> ();

    if  (
                search == ""
            &&  s == null
            &&  w == null
            &&  c.Count == 0
        )
        return result;

    IQueryable<Article> query = dbSet.AsQueryable ();

    if (search != "")
        query = query.Where (x => x.Title.Contains (search) || x.Summary.Contains (search));

    if (s != null)
        query = query.Where (x => x.SectionId == s.Id);

    if (w != null)
        query = query.Where (x => x.WebsiteId == w.Id);

    if (c.Count > 0)
    {
        List<long> cIds = c.Select (x => x.Id).ToList ();
        query = query.Where (art => art.Categories.Select (c => c.Id).Any (x => cIds.Contains (x)));
    }

    query = query.Include (x => x.Categories);

    result = await query.ToListAsync ();

    if (c.Count > 0)
    {
        List<long> cIds = c.Select (x => x.Id).ToList ();
        result = result.Where (art => cIds.All (cId => art.Categories.Select (c => c.Id).Contains (cId))).ToList ();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here is an example:

Let's say `c` will contain ids `9,10,11` and the articles collection is the following pseudo code:

```
List<article> articles = new List<Article> ()
{
    new Article () {Id = 1, Categories = "12,44,55"}
    new Article () {Id = 2, Categories = "7,8,9,10,11"}
    new Article () {Id = 3, Categories = "9,10,11"}
}
```

The linq query should return Article with Id `2` and `3` because both contains all of the ids present in `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions using `Intersect`, but we have to prepare data for intersection.

```cs
// articles query
var query = ...

var cIds = c.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var idsCount = cIds.Count();

// translating list of IDs to IQueryable
var categoryIdsQuery = dbContext.Categories
    .Where(c => cIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .Select(c => c.Id);

query = query
    .Where(art => art.Categories
        .Select(c => c.Id)
        .Intersect(categoryIdsQuery)
        .Count() == idsCount
    )
    .Include(x => x.Categories);
```

Comment: I just tried your code and the resulting SQL query (by adding ```.ToQueryString ()``` at the end is more complex than the one from my solution, therefore it isn;t helping me. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually it is best solution that i can imagine with EF and server side calculation.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is a LINQ query against SQLite that returns all the articles that have all the categories that I specify.

So you have a sequence of `Category` Ids and you want all `Articles`, each Article with only the Categories that are in your sequence of Category Ids.

I'm not sure what your variable 'c' is, but it seems to me that the following statement returns the Ids of all `c`:

```
List<long> cIds = c.Select (x => x.Id).ToList ();
```

If `c` is your sequence of Categories, then you will have the Ids of all existing categories. This will mean that you will have all Articles, each with all Categories.

If you have a local sequence of Category Ids, with a limited count (say about 250), then you should use `Contains`:

```
IEnumerable<long> categoryIds = ...
var articlesWithTheseCategories = dbContext.Articles.Select(article => new
{
    Id = article.Id,
    Categories = article.Categories
        .Where(category => categoryIds.Contains(category.Id)
        .ToList(),
})
```

So if you have CategoryIds 2, 3, and 12, this query will give you all Articles with only the Categories with ids 2, 3, 12.

If Article 40 has only Categories 20, 21, 21, then Article 40 will be in your result, but it will have an empty Categories list.

If you don't have your Category Ids locally, but you have a predicate to select the Category Ids, then your query will be like:

```
IQueryable<long> categoryIds = dbContext.Categories
    .Where(category => category.Status == StatusCode.Obsolete); // predicate

var articlesWithTheseCategories = dbContext.Articles.Select(article => new
{
    Id = article.Id,
    Categories = article.Categories
        .Where(category => categoryIds.Contains(category.Id)
        .ToList(),
});
```

Because your first query is an `IQueryable<...>` it is not executed yet. If you want you can make it one big statement:

```
var articlesWithTheseCategories = dbContext.Articles.Select(article => new
{
    Id = article.Id,
    Categories = article.Categories
        .Where(category => dbContext.Categories
            .Where(category => category.Status == StatusCode.Obsolete)
            .Contains(category.Id))
        .ToList(),
});
```

Although this will not improve efficiency, it surely deteriorates readability.

Comment: I don't want the articles that have ONLY the ids present in ```c```. I need those that have all of the ids in ```c```, yes, but if they have more, is not a problem. Plus I don't need a projection of the articles like you did with the Select. In any case I have updated the question adding the function where the query will be sed and an example of the result I need. Thanks in advance!